# Formatting column making the column text to disappear in latest Sharepoint online

Tags: column, json, formatting

Formatting column with JSON makes the column text to disappear in latest Sharepoint online.

E.g. if I try to use something like that:
`{ "elmType": "div", "txtContent": "@currentField" }`
saddenly I cannot see any file names etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Provide more details of what exactly you are trying to achieve.  Also, which type of column you are applying the formatting to?

Comment: I am trying to widen the column or wrap text in the "Name" column of my document collection listing. However, I have not come so far as simply putting the code I showed into the JSON formatting box causes the file/folde name, date created etc to disappear.